# Execute a periodic worker when the device is switched on

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-workmanager

I am developing a news reader based on a RSS feed. So far I created:

- a worker to retrieve the feed and convert it to a list of objects, so
  I can show it on a listview;
- a periodic worker which is executed according to the time settings of
  the application. This worker forces the execution of the refresh of
  the news list and it calls implicitely the first worker.

Everything works fine but I'd like the periodic worker to work everytime the device is switched on. So I created a broadcast receiver class; the method onReceive is called when the device is rebooted. The trouble is that if I call the periodic worker it will only run once and not periodically as expected. What do I do wrong? How can I make the app check if there are any new news for each startup, avoiding him to open the app? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Post your code.  We don't know what you're doing wrong without that.  In particular, post wherever you're registering with WorkManager or JobScheduler